# Can't find publish to web in the workspace

Tags: powerbi

Publish to web works perfectly, but when I add roles to the report in power BI desktop, then I can't find publish to web in my workspace.

Is there a solution or is it limited to pro users?

Answer (score 1):

One of the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web#limitations) of Publish to web is that it does not work with RLS. And if you think about it for a moment, it makes sense. If you implemented RLS in your report, this means that there is sensitive data in it, which should not be visible to some people (or to be visible only to some people, to be precise). But at the same time, you are making this sensitive data public, which makes no sense! And the other side of "public" is that there is no authentication and Power BI doesn't know who is looking at your report, so it can't apply the RLS policies.

One solution is to use [Secure embed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-embed-secure), but this requires each of the users, who will need access to this report, to have Power BI Pro license.

The best solution is to use the API to embed the report, which is described in [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content into an application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers).
.

You can also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58430715/ways-to-share-dashboards-and-reports-for-users-without-a-powerbi-account-and-not/58431358#58431358) for details how to implement it.